# What is the meaning of a matrix exponent of a scalar in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

For a scalar `c` and a `nxn`matrix `A`, what is the meaning of `c^A`?

E.g.

```
>> c=2;
>> A=[1 2; 3 4];
>> c^A

ans =

   10.4827   14.1519
   21.2278   31.7106
```

All I could find was [this section in the Mathworks documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mpower.html#btybl9u).

But what is the real meaning of that, is this a commonly accepted definition? Is this useful in real applications?

Any reference to a document with further details is appreciated.
(I am aware of the element-wise operation `c.^A`)

Comment: It has a central importance in numerical algebra. Look at the documentation of matrix exponential `expm`

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Matlab per se, actually not even with programming. Therefore: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: One use-case : Matrix exponentiation and logarithm operations are used to move to and from a tangent space and a point on a manifold (ie do a local linear approximation of a point on a manifold). For proper explanation you have to read more about  Lie algebra and Tangent spaces.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I met this when experimenting with MATLAB. I haven't found a similar operation in other languages. So surely it has "something" to do with MATLAB. However if you search the internet you won't find anything other than the brief documentation which just explain the implementation details. Therefore I believe my initial judgement was correct to post this in SO as the only thing I knew for sure is that this is related to MATLAB. If you are close voting, no offence, but that means you know the answer and it would be nice to briefly mention it (like SaurabhSaini) before voting.

Comment: @Anubis If I misjudged your question (and I still believe it does not belong here), four others did as well. You are free to edit your question and explain why we are all wrong and vote for reopening. And just because it has something too do with Matlab, it still does not mean it belongs here.  math.stackexchange.com also has a Matlab-tag. If you wouldn't have posted the link to `mpower` it would have been a valid question in my eyes, but with the link you're obviously knowing whats going on, searching for further mathematical explanation (I can't give you), so  math.se is the right place.

Comment: @Anubis And besides that, all languages I know of, which can deal with matrices, also offer a matrix exponent, e.g. [**python**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_power.html) or [**octave**](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Arithmetic-Ops.html).